# Save model to pickl module

Tags: python, machine-learning, pickle, predict

I used an extreme learning machine(ELM) for predicting video quality, and I want to save and load my model to pickle. I need to add python code to save and load my model to pickel library. Pleas any one can help me.

My code:

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler_X = MinMaxScaler()
scaler_Y = MinMaxScaler()
# fit_transform for training data:
X_train = scaler_X.fit_transform(train.values[:,:-1])
y_train = scaler_Y.fit_transform(train.values[:,-1:])
#print(y_train)
# only transform for test (unseen) data:
X_test = scaler_X.transform(test.values[:,:-1])
y_test = scaler_Y.transform(test.values[:,-1:])

input_size = X_train.shape[1]

#---------------------------(Number of neurons)-------
hidden_size = 26

#---------------------------(To fix the RESULT)-------
seed =26   # can be any number, and the exact value does not matter
np.random.seed(seed)

#---------------------------(weights & biases)------------
input_weights = np.random.normal(size=[input_size,hidden_size])
biases = np.random.normal(size=[hidden_size])

#----------------------(Activation Function)----------
def relu(x):
   return np.maximum(x, 0, x)

#--------------------------(Calculations)----------
def hidden_nodes(X):
    G = np.dot(X, input_weights)
    G = G + biases
    H = relu(G)
    return H

#Output weights 
output_weights = np.dot(pinv2(hidden_nodes(X_train)), y_train)

#------------------------(Def prediction)---------
def predict(X):
    out = hidden_nodes(X)
    out = np.dot(out, output_weights)
    return out
#------------------------------------(Make_PREDICTION)--------------
prediction = predict(X_test)
unscaler_prediction=prediction*(5-1)+1
unscaler_y_test=y_test*(5-1)+1
```

Comment: Have you read the Pickle documentation? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I faced problem when I write the following code:  pickle.dump(elm('model.pkl','wb'))
model=pickle.load(open('model.pkl','rb'))  .  I get this message error :NameError: name 'elm' is not defined.     I need to know how can I define my model. @Mike L

Comment: Did you ask this question before? You seem to have the exact same problem, elm is not defined anywhere.